# How to reuse function for 10 sec. Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function which is calling to JSON:

```
function inspect(){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'addtest.json',
        dataType: "JSON",
        async : false,
        success: function(response) {
            for (n=0; n<20; n++){
                var result = (response[n][3])
                    if(result == "Done"){

                        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Test OK"

                        n=20;
                    }
            }
        },

        error: function(response) {
            alert("No File")
        }
    });
}
```

This is working fine. 
Content in file addtest.json is not static. It's changing when you start test.
My question is. How to make that ajax function recall for 10sec. If result == "Done" then it will stop. If after 10sec trying result != "Done" then it will stop with alert("not tested")

Comment: Your question is unclear and/or there isn't enough information here...how are you generating `addtest.json`?

Comment: Do you want to wait 10 seconds to see if the request times out?  Or, do you want to retry the request multiple times if it fails?

Comment: Just leave addtest.json. It is genereted by different app.

Comment: Retry for 10sec in case of fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using setTimeout

[SetTimeOut Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)